# Storing the EOF (End of File) character in a char type

Tags: c

I read in the Dennis Ritchie's *The C Programming Language* book that `int` must be used for a variable to hold EOF – to make it sufficiently large so that it can hold EOF value – not `char`. But following code works fine:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

main()  { 
  char c; 
  c=getchar(); 
  while(c!=EOF)  { 
    putchar(c); 
    c=getchar(); 
  } 
}
```

When there is no more input, `getchar` returns EOF. And in the above program, the variable `c`, with char type, is able to hold it successfully.

Why does this work? As per the explanation in the book above mentioned, the code should not work.

Comment: [There is no EOF character.](https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/)

Comment: This code is likely to fail if you read a character with the value `0xff`. Storing the result of `getchar()` in an `int` solves that problem. Your question is essentially the same as question 12.1 in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com), which is an excellent resource. (Also, `main()` should be `int main(void)`, and it wouldn't hurt to add a `return 0;` before the closing `}`.)

Comment: @delnan: The linked article isn't quite right about how Unix treats control-D.  It doesn't close the input stream; it merely causes any fread() which is blocking on the console to return immediately with any as-yet-unread data.  Many programs interpret a zero-byte return from fread() as indicating EOF, but the file will in fact remain open and able to supply more input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code seems to work, because the implicit type conversions accidentally happen to do the right thing.

`getchar()` returns an `int` with a value that either fits the range of `unsigned char` or is `EOF` (which must be negative, usually it is -1). Note that `EOF` itself is not a character, but a signal that there are no more characters available.

When storing the result from `getchar()` in `c`, there are two possibilities. Either the type `char` can represent the value, in which case that is the value of `c`. Or the type `char` *can not* represent the value. In that case, it is not defined what will happen. Intel processors just chop off the high bits that don't fit in the new type (effectively reducing the value modulo 256 for `char`), but you should not rely on that.

The next step is to compare `c` with `EOF`. As `EOF` is an `int`, `c` will be converted to an `int` as well, preserving the value stored in `c`. If `c` could store the value of `EOF`, then the comparison will succeed, but if `c` could *not* store the value, then the comparison will fail, because there has been an irrecoverable loss of information while converting `EOF` to type `char`.

It seems your compiler chose to make the `char` type signed and the value of `EOF` small enough to fit in `char`. If `char` were unsigned (or if you had used `unsigned char`), your test would have failed, because `unsigned char` can't hold the value of `EOF`.

---

Also note that there is a second problem with your code. As `EOF` is not a character itself, but you force it into a `char` type, there is very likely a character out there that gets misinterpreted as being `EOF` and for half the possible characters it is undefined if they will be processed correctly.

Comment: Coercing to type `char` values outside the range `CHAR_MIN`..`CHAR_MAX` will is required to either yield an Implementation-Defined value, yield a bit pattern which the implementation defines as a trap representation, or raise an implementation-defined signal.  In most cases, implementations would have to go through a lot of extra work to do anything other than two's-complement reduction.  If people on the Standards Committee subscribed to the idea that compilers should be encouraged to implement behaviors consistent with that of most other compilers in the absence of reasons to do otherwise...

Comment: ...I would regard such coercion as being reliable (not to say that code shouldn't document its intentions, but that `(signed char)x` is should be considered clearer and just as safe as `((unsigned char)x ^ CHAR_MAX+1))-(CHAR_MAX+1)`.)  As it is, I don't see any likelihood of compilers implementing any other behavior complying with today's standard; the one danger would be that the Standard might be changed to break the behavior in the supposed interest of "optimization".

Comment: @supercat: The standard is written such that no compiler has to produce code that has behaviour that is not naturally supported by the processor it targets. Most of the undefined behaviour is there because (at the time of writing the standard) not all processors behaved consistently. With the compilers getting more mature, compiler writers have started taking advantage of the undefined behaviour to make more aggressive optimisations.

Comment: Historically, the intention of the Standard was mostly as you describe, though the Standard describes some behaviors in sufficient detail as to require compilers for some common platforms to generate more code than would be required under a looser specification.  The type coercion in `int i=129; signed char c=i;` is one such behavior.  Relatively few processors have an instruction that would make `c` equal `i` when it's in the range -127 to +127 and would yield any consistent mapping of other values of `i` to values in the range -128 to +127 that differed from two's-complement reduction, or...

Comment: ...would consistently raise a signal in such cases.  Since the Standard requires that implementations either yield a consistent mapping or consistently raise a signal, the only platforms where the Standard would leave room for something other than two's-complement reduction would be things like DSPs with saturating-arithmetic hardware.  As for the historical basis for Undefined Behavior, I would say that the issue isn't just with hardware platforms.  Even on a platform where overflow would behave in a very consistent fashion, it may be useful to have a compiler trap it...

Comment: ...in cases where untrapped overflows would cause a program to produce incorrect results that might e.g. cause an engineer to erroneously believe a building would be strong enough to withstand its intended loads.  Different programs have different requirements with regard to their handling of invalid inputs, and one of the reasons C could thrive was that different compilers could strike their own compromises between predictability and efficiency.  Today, alas, the prevailing philosophy is that both should be thrown out the window (if code needs to compute either `x << (y & 31)` or...

Comment: ...`(unsigned char)y > 31 ? 0 : x << (unsigned char)y` and doesn't care which, writing the expression the former way will make execution needlessly slow on ARM processors, and writing it the latter way will make it needlessly slow on x86 processors; if, as was historically the case on 99% of compilers, `x << y` meant "Generate whichever of the above expressions would be more convenient in any given case", that would allow compilers for both platforms to generate optimal code.)

Comment: Is "effectively reducing the value modulo 256 for `char`" correct? If `char` is `signed char` on a machine and supports values from -128 to 127, calculating modulo 256 for a result like 128 which is too large won't help, would it?